# Row count error after filter(with if statement)

Tags: javascript

I have this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b42vn2nh/49/) which hide and show the  according to keyword input (#search-criteria). Most are working fine but there is this bug which I am not sure where it is coming from (even after looking at console.log).

Problem:
when search result should be "0", it shows as "1"
example A: keyword="apple", search result="2" 
example B: keyword="applee", search result="0"
example C: keyword="appleee", search result="1" *this should be "0", and there is no row showing but it counts "1"!?
NOTE: I append a new row when search is not found but remove it later.

```
$("#search-criteria").on("keyup", function () {

    var keyword = $(this).val().replace(/[Ａ-Ｚａ-ｚ０-９]/g, function (td_word) {
        return String.fromCharCode(td_word.charCodeAt(0) - 0xFEE0);
    }).toLowerCase();
    var row = "table#table-body tbody>tr";

    if (keyword !== "") {
        $(row).each(function () {
            var td_word = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            var srowCount = $(row).filter(":visible").length;
            //shorthand if function
            $(this).closest(row)[td_word.indexOf(keyword) !== -1 ? 'show' : 'hide']();
            document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = srowCount;
            console.log(srowCount);

            if (srowCount === 0) {
                $("table#table-body tbody").last().append('<tr class="s_empty"><td colspan="5">Search not found</td></tr>');
                $("tr.s_empty").show();
            } else {
                $("tr.s_empty").remove();
            }

        });
    } else {
        $(row).show();
        document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = $(row).length;
    }

});
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you are appending a row "Search not found" to your table, then counting the number of rows in the table, which is counting this appended row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working fine

```
//search function
$("#search-criteria").on("keyup", function () {
var keyword = $(this).val().replace(/[Ａ-Ｚａ-ｚ０-９]/g, function (td_word) {
    return String.fromCharCode(td_word.charCodeAt(0) - 0xFEE0);
}).toLowerCase();
var row = "table#table-body tbody>tr";

if (keyword !== "") {
    $(row).each(function () {
        var td_word = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
        //shorthand if function
        $(this).closest(row)[td_word.indexOf(keyword) !== -1 ? 'show' : 'hide']();
    });
    var srowCount = $(row).filter(":visible").length;
    document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = srowCount;
    if (srowCount === 0) {
        if(!$(row).last().hasClass('s_empty'))
        {
            $("table#table-body tbody").last().append('<tr class="s_empty"><td colspan="5">Search not found</td></tr>');
        }
        $("tr.s_empty").show();
    } else {
        $("tr.s_empty").remove();
    }
} else {
    $("tr.s_empty").remove();
    $(row).show();
    document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = $(row).length;
}

});
```

Comment: Thanks Sachink, it works now. I thought I had to write an if inside other if, but it seems having it separated (your code) solved the problem. But now after search, when I clear the input to blank the result will be 9. I added .remove() in line 53 and it seems to create other problems....when I back space.

Comment: You can add .remove() in else block  
    else {
        $("tr.s_empty").remove();
        $(row).show();
        document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = $(row).length;
    }

Comment: Sachink, I made some changes for the orders. Now, the table row for "search not found" is not showing. Mind to take a look, please?  http://jsfiddle.net/revzephyr/b42vn2nh/58/

Comment: i have added a count of rows outside onkeyup (line 53-55), so that at initial the count information will be displayed. It is working so far, but is it bad? For example, will it cause loop error, etc.? http://jsfiddle.net/revzephyr/b42vn2nh/70/ Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you are taking rowCount first and then you are doing show hide, try this

```
$("#search-criteria").on("keyup", function () {

    var keyword = $(this).val().replace(/[Ａ-Ｚａ-ｚ０-９]/g, function (td_word) {
        return String.fromCharCode(td_word.charCodeAt(0) - 0xFEE0);
    }).toLowerCase();
    var row = "table#table-body tbody>tr";

    if (keyword !== "") {
        $(row).each(function () {
            var td_word = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            var srowCount;
            //shorthand if function
            $(this).closest(row)[td_word.indexOf(keyword) !== -1 ? 'show' : 'hide']();
            srowCount = $(row).filter(":visible").length;
            document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = srowCount;
            console.log(srowCount);

            if (srowCount === 0) {
                $("table#table-body tbody").last().append('<tr class="s_empty"><td colspan="5">Search not found</td></tr>');
                $("tr.s_empty").show();
            } else {
                $("tr.s_empty").remove();
            }

        });
    } else {
        $(row).show();
        document.getElementById('count').innerHTML = $(row).length;
    }

});
```

Comment: Thank you Vaibhav, I understood what you are saying and I believe and it is due to ordering. Although your code doesn't work. Thanks for helping.

Comment: There will be some error while copying, intension is to calculate rowcount after show:hide logic